# Which are the smtp_settings for sending email with an account that uses Exchange?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've configured smtp_settings for sending emails under Google Apps accounts several times, but now that I need to configure it for an email account using exchange it throws me `execution expired` message with the following settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:address => 'smtp',
:port => 995,
:domain => 'domain',
:user_name => 'username',
:password => 'password',
:authentication => :plain,
}
```

The smtp, domain, user name and password were given to me by the client. The port I think it must be 995 (as it uses SSL).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured that the port was 25 instead of 995 and the authentication was login instead of plain.